# ESRI file coordinate confusion

Tags: coordinates, esri-grid-format

I have a batch of (binary) ESRI files containing 25m resolution raster data.  I need to check my interpretation of the OSGB coordinates therein.

`gdalinfo` reports the following for a file containing a 3578 x 3833 raster:

```
Pixel Size = (25.000000000000000,-25.000000000000000)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  486425.000,  222650.000) (  0d44'37.94"W, 51d53'42.91"N)
Lower Left  (  486425.000,  126825.000) (  0d46' 2.31"W, 51d 2' 1.48"N)
Upper Right (  575875.000,  222650.000) (  0d33'18.65"E, 51d52'27.15"N)
Lower Right (  575875.000,  126825.000) (  0d30'27.19"E, 51d 0'48.00"N)
Center      (  531150.000,  174737.500) (  0d 6'43.71"W, 51d27'21.30"N)
```

The clarification I need (given the negative Y pixel size) is whether the upper left coordinate given corresponds to the NW corner of the top-left-most cell, or the SW corner.

Comment: This question is more about gdalinfo output than Grid format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upper left is the NW corner.

The negative Y pixel size is to do with storing pixels from the top down while measuring the other way.

Comment: thanks - this is what I had surmised.  By extension then, the Lower Left value is the NW corner of the bottom left cell, and the true minimum Y extent is 25m less (i.e. 126800) ?

Comment: I think they are the actual corners